# How to remove navigation addListener

Tags: react-native

When Is state changed the addListener is removed and added again with changed state This is what I expected but It's never removed
so I tried remove when the state is changed and I called removeListener same time but They're not working

**removeListener**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const {page, pageIdx, tab} = pageInfo

    const remove = navigation.addListener('state', ({data: {state: {routes, index}}}) => {
        if (routes[index].name === name) {
          if (pageIdx)
              getMatchItem(`usr/goods/match/buy/history/${tab}/${page}`)
          else
              getItem(`usr/goods/auction/bid/${tab}/${page}`)
        }
    })

    return () => {
      navigation.removeListener("state", () => {
        console.log("removed")
      })
    }
}, [pageInfo])
```

**remove function**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const {page, pageIdx, tab} = pageInfo

    const remove = navigation.addListener('state', ({data: {state: {routes, index}}}) => {
        if (routes[index].name === name) {
          if (pageIdx)
              getMatchItem(`usr/goods/match/buy/history/${tab}/${page}`)
          else
              getItem(`usr/goods/auction/bid/${tab}/${page}`)
        }
    })

    return remove
}, [pageInfo])
```

so How to remove or stop addListener? or How to changed states in callBack in addListener

Answer (score 0):

Please keep only one `useEffect` and the second one (`remove function`) is correct. Just add `navigation` to the dependency list of `useEffect`. You should trace `pageInfo` inside the callback of addListener to get to know if it is really changed.